# How to remove a newly created model using Ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm implementing a view for creating a new user.

```
App.UserNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model : function(params) {
        return this.store.createRecord('user');
   }
});
```

On the UserNewController there is a method which is triggered if the user presses cancel.

```
App.UserNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   //... code
   actions: {
       //.. other actions
       cancel: function(){
            var model = this.get('model');
            model.destroyRecord();
            this.transitionToRoute('users');
       }
   }
});
```

I'm always getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willCommit` on <App.User:ember751:null> while in state root.deleted.saved.
```

I've tried using an alternative:

```
  model.deleteRecord();
  model.save();
```

I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1669, the issue might be already fixed in newer Ember versions. I'm using `Ember version 1.5.1` and `Ember-Data version 1.0.0-beta.6`

The workaround was to do a `dirty` check.

```
var model = this.get('model');
model.deleteRecord();
if (model.get('isDirty')) {
    model.save();
}
this.transitionToRoute('users');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might have to do with the fact that model.destroyRecord() returns a promise and that you are transitioning before that promise fulfilled. I have been using the following:

```
var model = this.get('model');
var _this = this;

// assuming you are working with a new model and not on say an edit page
// this will delete the new record and once the promise returns will transition routes
if (model.get('isNew')) {
  model.destroyRecord().then(function() {
    _this.transitionToRoute('route name');
  }
}
```

So that the transition only happens once the promise has been fulfilled. I am still an ember scrub but I figured it wouldn't hurt.